# actionscript flex, how to send browser width to the swf itself

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, adobe

I'm working with flex, but actionscript ideas are just as good.

The flex `<s:Application>` tag has `height="100%" width="100%"` so the swf fits the browser as the browser gets resized.

My problem is that I have a `<s:Label>` that I need to position based on the real/current size of the browser.

```
<s:Application height="100%" width="100%">
     .....
     <s:Label text="hello" x="?" y=">" />

</s:Application>
```

I heard it's possible to use `Application.application.width;` but I get a compile error, that it doesn't know what that is.

Any ideas how to do this. I'm trying to get the current size of the swf in the browser, as the browser resizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell the following should work. Application.application simply is the same as this provided you are in the base application. The binding should allow the size to change after initialization.

```
<s:Application height="100%" width="100%">
     .....
     <s:Label text="hello" x="{width}" y="" />

</s:Application>
```

Edit : I just checked and it does work. To put your Label in the middle of the stage you simply have to put it like that

```
<s:Application height="100%" width="100%">
         .....
         <s:Label text="hello" x="{width/2}" y="{height/2}" />

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could only know stage size when element is added inside stage, you could try a eventdelegate like this

```
app.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
private function init(evt:Event):void{
   trace(stage.stageWidth);
   trace(stage.stageHeight);
}
```

Comment: That won't update on browser resize though, but only on the initial size.

Comment: There is also a RESIZE event, to be use like stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler). http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/liquid_gui_03.html

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript function on browser resize.  From there get the reference to the swf, and call the AS function to resize the label.  Pass the browser width/height.

See example [here](http://blog.circlecube.com/2008/02/tutorial/actionscript-javascript-communication/)

UPDATE: Correction: ExternalInterface goes AS to JS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you are trying to do.  `x` and `y` are positional elements, `width` and `height` are size elements.  If you are positioning the label you should probably use `top, left, right` and `bottom` rather than `x` and `y` if you want it to size as the parent control sizes.

If you want the label centered you can use `horizontalCenter` and `verticalCenter`.

If you put it inside a layout control like a `panel` or a `canvas` you can just set its `left` and `right` to 0 and have the parent canvas size.

If your label is always in a different place depending on the size, you can override `updateDisplayList` to set the position.  That holds whether you put it inside a layout control or not.